# numpy mask for 2d array with all values in 1d array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to convert a 2d matrix of dates to boolean matrix based on dates in a 1d matrix. i.e.,

```
[[20030102, 20030102, 20070102],
 [20040102, 20040102, 20040102].,
 [20050102, 20050102, 20050102]]
```

should become

```
[[True, True, False],
 [False, False, False].,
 [True, True, True]]
```

if I provide a 1d array [20010203, **20030102**, 20030501, **20050102**, 20060101]

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np

dateValues = np.array(
    [[20030102, 20030102, 20030102],
     [20040102, 20040102, 20040102],
     [20050102, 20050102, 20050102]])

requestedDates = [20010203, 20030102, 20030501, 20050102, 20060101]

ix = np.in1d(dateValues.ravel(), requestedDates).reshape(dateValues.shape)

print(ix)
```

**Returns:**

```
[[ True  True  True]
 [False False False]
 [ True  True  True]]
```

Refer to `numpy.in1d` for more information (documentation):
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html

Answer (score 1):

```
a = np.array([[20030102, 20030102, 20070102],
              [20040102, 20040102, 20040102],
              [20050102, 20050102, 20050102]])

b = np.array([20010203, 20030102, 20030501, 20050102, 20060101])

>>> a.shape
(3, 3)
>>> b.shape
(5,)
>>>
```

For the comparison, you need to [broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/basics.broadcasting.html) `b` onto `a` by adding an axis to `a`. - this compares each element of `a` with each element of `b`

```
>>> mask = a[...,None] == b
>>> mask.shape
(3, 3, 5)
>>>
```

Then use `np.any()` to see if there are any matches

```
>>> np.any(mask, axis = 2, keepdims = False)
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

---

timeit.Timer comparison with `in1d`:

```
>>> 
>>> t = Timer("np.any(a[...,None] == b, axis = 2)","from __main__ import np, a, b")
>>> t.timeit(10000)
0.13268041338812964
>>> t = Timer("np.in1d(a.ravel(), b).reshape(a.shape)","from __main__ import np, a, b")
>>> t.timeit(10000)
0.26060646913566643
>>>
```

Comment: While clever, this is actually pretty cumbersome and inefficient compared to @ode2k 's answer. +1 anyway.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - I was wondering, ```in1d``` must go through a similar process.  Less efficient how? Did you test them?